# Generate html from graphical UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a CMS project where users can drag and drop different components(such as button, div, etc) from components menu on canvas area. Once they are happy about their layout then they click on button finish. What I want is when finish button is clicked then in popup they should see html and its appropriate CSS code.

**How can I parse through those components and generate html, css and Javascript if necessary?**

Are there any solutions available? I could not find any after googling.

Comment: This is a very broad question. In my oppinion This can not be answered without a minimal example and a clear problem statement.

Comment: Something like, user drag and drop 2 labels, and 2 input fields and one submit button, then user changed some colors of the background of the form then press finish to get its html.

Comment: But you asked for css and javascript also. Creating an WYSIWYG editor delivering html, css and javascript as a result is not a generic task and requires a lot of effort. If you want only the HTML of the items, you should not use canvas at all. You could just clone predefined html elements in an drop area and read it's inner `html` on finish. But this will not be what you are striving for.

Comment: Numerous ways this can be done and a lot depends on use case. Question is far too broad

Answer (score 0):

maybe this approach  is different but.
can you use of svg element? because with svg you can get positions for every element and then use for whatever you want (like get positions for example).

here some useful tutorials:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_svg.htm
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp (for some reason some people don't like this site)